# Preventing frequently updated nodes from keeping them on the top of View

Tags: 6, views, nodes

I have a view that lists content profile node and set the `sort criteria` to `node:Updated date`.

However, the problem is that some of the users updates their content profile node everyday to keep it on the top of the list.

I need to user `sort criteria` to `node:Updated date` but is there any way to prevent their nodes from being on the top of view?

Lest's say for example, within one week after their last update even if they update it again it stays where it is now and doesn't get to the top or somthing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible using views out of the box! Because updated date is stored as a single value in the database. If a user updates again the new value overrides old value.

So, there is no way views can track ***within one week after their last update even if they update it again*** .

You need to use hook_nodeapi either to track all updates in separate table and query that table to list users.